# Unable to reroute in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to create a new page in symfony but I can not access it

this is my file

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class About extends Controller

{
    /**
     * @Route("/about")
     */
    public function aboutAction()
    {
        return new Response(
            '<html><body>This page is about ME</body></html>'
        );
    }
}
```

When I use `php bin/console debug:router` It shows name:app_about_about(I don't understand why it has this name) and path:/about . But when I try to load the page I get 404 error

Comment: Look if You dont have any prefix set in your `routing.yml`

Comment: No, only resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/" and type: annotation

Comment: what url are You entering ?? `http://localhost/about` ??

Answer (score 0):

Try after importing:

`use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;`

Comment: It does nothing, I don't know if I access the page correctly, because I access default page like this. `https://localhost/obchod/web/` and I want to access about page like this `https://localhost/obchod/web/about`

Answer (score 0):

Just rename your file to ./MyBundle/Controller/AboutController.php and rename the class :

```
class AboutController extends Controller
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try with route name. You should also rename your controller by `AboutController`.

```
 /**
 * @Route("/about", name="about_page")
 */
```

Comment: That doesn't work,  I changed file name and controller name, and still nothing

Comment: Have you tried by changing route name also in annotations?